# Unable to get value of first td in a row

Tags: jquery, dom

Here is html form and I want to get `value` of first `td` tag of table:

```
<tr class="tr_entry">
    <td><input readonly="" name="product_id[]" id="product_id" value="xyz-20" type="text"></td>
    <td>
    <select id="purpose_id" name="purpose_id[]">
                        <option value="100"> abc</option>
                                <option value="115">   abc</option>
                                <option value="116"> abc</option>
                                <option value="98"> abc</option>
                        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input id="recive_date" readonly="" name="recive_date[]" class="dp"></td>
    <td>
        <select id="funding_source_id" name="funding_source_id[]">
                                <option value="1">abc</option>
                                <option value="2">abc</option>
                            </select>
    </td>
    <td><button id="open_modal" type="button" class=" btn btn-primary add_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button></td>
</tr>
```

I have tried this but it gives me `undefined` in `alert`.

```
$(document).on('click','#open_modal',function(){
    var vacc = $(this).find('td:first').val();
    alert(vacc);
});
```

and also

```
var vacc = $(this).parent().siblings(":first").text();
alert(vacc);
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('table').find('td:first').children().val();` or just `$('#product_id').val()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
$(document).on('click','#open_modal',function(){
    var vacc = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child input').val();
    alert(vacc);
});
```

`.find` only searches for given selector among the descendents of the current element.

Instead, `.closest('tr')` will select the current row, and then you can search the relevant `td` element.

Also, you should select the `input` element using `.find('td:first-child input')`, or something more specific. But selecting with `.find('td:first-child')` merely selects the `<td>` element - which does not have a value attribute.

Comment: Why `parents()`? Use `closest('tr')`.

Comment: @Tushar It is just a matter or personal preference. Does `.closest` have any performance benefits over `.parents`?

Comment: `parents` will go up the DOM tree to find all ancestors, while `closest` will get the first matching ancestor and return.

Comment: @Tushar I didn't realize that `.parents` was merely filtering among the ancestors. `.closest` is certainly more appropriate. I've updated the answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of missunderstanding,

first;

`td`element doesn't have `val()` function you can access with `html()`

second;

```
var vacc = $(this).find('td:first-child input').val();
```

`this` in above code referenced to row's button hence you can access tr row,

you can use below two different codes **parent** and **closest** but my advice is `closest`

```
var vacc = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();
```

you can access `td` element text as string and it looks your `input` html code `<input readonly="" name="product_id[]" id="product_id" value="xyz-20" type="text">`

if you want to access input value then you should use

```
var vacc = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').find('input').val();
```